# Is it possible that your python code written under Windows may not work in Linux? In particular I am working with OpenCV library

Tags: python, windows, opencv, ubuntu, cross-platform

```
blue_lower = np.array([40, 30, 30], np.uint8)
blue_upper = np.array([130, 255, 255],  np.uint8)
blue = cv2.inRange(blue, blue_lower, blue_upper)
```

Is it possible that in some code written in Python, in particular, one that uses Opencv library, works in Windows but not in Ubnutu?

I swear the above code worked in windows. However I had to change it to

```
blue_lower = np.array([40, 30, 30], dtype =np.uint8)
blue_upper = np.array([130, 255, 255],  dtype = np.uint8)
blue = cv2.inRange(blue, blue_lower, blue_upper)
```

in order to make it work in Ubuntu..

Comment: is there an error message?  Are you using current versions of python on both systems?

Comment: Also, what version of numpy are you using (and is the same for both systems)

Comment: Note that per http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array, the signature for array is numpy.array(object, dtype=None, copy=True, order=None, subok=False, ndmin=0). Technically, both ways of calling will produce the same result, as long as both of your versions of numpy are the using that signature.

Comment: I am using the same version of python, but not sure about Numpy... The thing is I installed Numpy on Windows and I did not install again in linux, so I suppose the numpy version should be the same..